# DataGridView throwing "InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid..." when adding a row

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview

I want an OpenFileDialog to come up when a user clicks on a cell, then display the result in the cell.

It all works, except that the DataGridView displays an extra row, for adding values to the list it's bound to.  The row shows up if `dataGridView.AllowUserToAddNewRows == true`, which is what I want.  What I don't want is for the application to crash when that row is edited programatically; instead, it should do exactly what it would do if the user had edited that row manually (add the new row to the underlying list, push another empty row onto the grid for adding values).

I read about SendKeys.Send(), which should make the DataGridView behave exactly as though the user had typed the value in; however, it does not work either.  Here is what I am trying:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;

    //simply doing a cell.Value = etc. will cause the program to crash
    cell.ReadOnly = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns[cell.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = false;
    dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
    SendKeys.Send(openFileDialog1.FileName + "{Enter}");
    dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    cell.ReadOnly = true;
    dataGridView1.Columns[cell.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = true;
}
//I would expect the FileName would be in the cell now, and a new empty
//row tacked onto the end of the DataGridView, but it's not; the DataGridView
//is not changed at all.
```

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting when you set `cell.Value`?

Comment: @Zach: When I click on the empty cell, it fills in the value correctly, but it does not add another empty row.  When I click away from the row, the values in all cells on that final row disappear (this only happens for that final row).  When I then click on the final row again, I get an InvalidOperationException: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."  dataGridView1_CellClick is the only event I am handling on that form (shown above)

Comment: `AllowUserToAddRows = false`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was having the same problem when trying to programattically edit cells with a binding source.
""Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

Which operation? What State?  So helpful.

My code seem to work fine except when editing the last row in the grid.

Turns out the key is DataGridView.NotifiyCurrentCelldirty(true)

The correct sequence for programatically editing a cell, so it works the same as if the user did it.
(A new empty row appears when changing a cell in the last row) is something like this:

1) Make the cell to edit the current cell (do what ever you need to the current currentcell, first
   like calling endEdit if it is in edit mode.)

2) Call DataGridview.BeginEdit(false)

3) Call DataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true)

4) Modify the value.

5) Call DataGridView.EndEdit()

And you'll want to do something for the RowValidating and RowValidated events.

One of my routines for updating a cell value looks like this:

This is from a method in my class derived from DataGridView.
You could do the same thing from the containing form,  calling
through a DataGridView instance, because the methods are public.
Here the calls are using an impliciit 'this.'

```
    private void EnterTime()
    {
        if (CurrentRow == null) return;

        SaveCurrentCell(); // Calls EndEdit() if CurrentCell.IsInEditMode
        DataGridViewCell previous = CurrentCell;

        CurrentCell = CurrentRow.Cells[CatchForm.TimeColumn];
        BeginEdit(false);
        NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        CurrentCell.Value = DateTime.Now;
        EndEdit();

        CurrentCell = previous;

    }
```

I’m not sure why a separate call is needed.

Why doesn’t BeginEdit, or actually modifying the cell value, cause the right
things to happen?

And if you move the NotifyCurrentCellDirty call to after you actually modify the cell,
it doesn’t behave correctly either.   All very annoying.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to add this, Darrel. I've long since forgotten about this problem, but I'll mark this as correct, because I have no idea why my workaround worked.

Comment: In my case, I also needed to call CurrentCell.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(false) after EndEdit()

Answer (score 20):

I found a workaround on [this page](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/31_2006_7_0_0_795229/DataGridView-bound-to-object-Operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object-.htm), though I don't know why it works

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Create a BindingSource, set its DataSource to my list,
    //set the DataGrid's DataSource to the BindindingSource...
    _bindingSource.AddingNew += OnAddingNewToBindingSource;
}

private void OnAddingNewToBindingSource(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count == _bindingSource.Count)
    {
        _bindingSource.RemoveAt(_bindingSource.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

I'm getting very sick of spending **so much time** dealing with Visual Studio bugs...

Comment: +1 for question and answer - thanks, this just works and helped us a lot.

Comment: +1 Thank you!  I've been searching for a solution for few days now and this did the trick.

Comment: The reason it works is because on a DataGridView where AllowUserToAddRows is true, it adds an empty row at the end of its rows which if bound to a list creates a null element at the end of your list. Your code removes that element and then the AddNew in the BindingList will trigger the DataGridView to add it again.

Comment: First line in event could be `var bindingSource = (BindingSource) sender;` ie don't need to make `_bindingSource` a field just for this

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't help me.... In the case leading up to this error, where this event is called, gridRowCount is 1 and binding source is 0. When the actual exception happens on the following add, this AddingNew event doesn't get a chance to run and continues on to the exception

Answer (score 4):

This is old, but I am running VS2010 and just come across this issue.  I have a `DataGridView` bound to a `List<T>` using a `BindingList<T>`.  I have a drag n' drop event on my `DataGridView` and it would throw this exception *after* deleting all rows from the DGV (except for the last blank one which one cannot delete) and *then* adding new rows to the DGV in the `DragDrop` handler via the `BindingList<T>`.  This exception was not thrown if I simply added rows manually editing individual cells.

One solution I read said to handle the `BindingList<T>.AddNew` event, but I found that this event did not fire when calling `BindingList<T>.Add()` within the `DragDrop` event handler (I'm not sure why).  I solved the issue by adding

```
if(bindingList.Count == 0)
    bindingList.RemoveAt(0)
```

inside of the `DragDrop` event handler *before* adding new objects to `bindingList`.  It seemed that adding an object to the `bindingList` failed when the only "object" in the `bindingList` was the one associated to the final blank row.  The point of a `BindingList<T>` is to allow the developer to work with it *instead* of the DGV directly, but it seems doing so can cause problems in border cases.

The relationship between DGV rows and `BindingList<T>` rows seems to be a bit of a gray area.  I have not spent much time investigating this, but it is not clear to me what is the state of the "object" in the `BindingList<T>` associated to the final (empty) row of the DGV.  However, it does seem like the "object" at the end is only instantiated "correctly" when you interact with the final row directly (not via a `DataSource`).

Comment: Awesome. I had teh same problem. I used `if (DataGridView.Rows.Count == bindingList.Count) { bindingList.RemoveAt(source.Count - 1); }` at the start of the drop handler and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int row = e.RowIndex;
            int clmn = e.ColumnIndex;
            if(e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.Rows.Count- 1)
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[clmn].Value = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
```

---

**EDIT**
I didn't notice that you are binding your datagridview :(
Ok, to solve it: use binding source, set its DataSource property to your list, then set the data source of the data grid view to this binding source. Now, the code should look like so:

```
public partial class frmTestDataGridView : Form
    {
        BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
        List<string> datasource = new List<string>();
        public frmTestDataGridView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            datasource.Add("item1");
            datasource.Add("item2");
            datasource.Add("item3");

            bindingSource1.DataSource = datasource;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                int row = e.RowIndex;
                int clmn = e.ColumnIndex;

                if (e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    bindingSource1.Add("");
                }
                dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[clmn].Value = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound."

Comment: And if I try to add to the BindingList instead, it gives me the same "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

Comment: Oops! I didn't notice that you are binding the gridview to a list! I updated my answer above. Please, check it and let us know the result.

Comment: Nope - using the `BindingSource.Add()` method gives me spot-on-spot the exact same results as using `cell.Value = something` (see my comment to Zach above)

Comment: I found a workaround, +1 for your time anyways though, thank you!

Comment: It should be mentioned (for future googlers of this problem) that setting cell.Value still does **not** automatically add a new row: Sameh's code does, though.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use `Row.BeginEdit()` and `Row.EndEdit()` if you get this error while editing a value in a row, using DataGrid or GridEX from Janus (in my case). The sample code that Darrel Lee posted here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143590/1278771) remind me to use these instructions that I forgot to use and this solved the problem for me.