# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object when adding to BindingList of DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I get this exception when adding to my BindingList that is attached to a DataGridView

```
    Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.ProcessListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.currencyManager_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.InnerList_ListChanged(Object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.FireListChanged(ListChangedType type, Int32 index)
   at System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
```

Confused as to why because it works in my other program

```cs
        private static readonly BindingList<SocketConnectionData> ClientDatas = new BindingList<SocketConnectionData>();
//stuff in between
            _form.dataGridView1.DataSource = ClientDatas;
//stuff in between
            _form.dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                var connectionData = new SocketConnectionData
                {
                    LinkedSocket = currentSocket
                };
                try
                {
                    ClientDatas.Add(connectionData);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }

                _form.dataGridView1.DataSource = ClientDatas;
            }));
```

*the .invoke is ran in another void*

Comment: Why are you setting the DataSource directly and then calling Invoke? If you're on the UI thread then why the Invoke and if you're not then don't set the DataSource.

Comment: When I set the DataSource it refreshes the DataGridView but removing that doesn't fix my issue. I also removed it from the Invoke to no avail. @jmcilhinney

Comment: I think you need to provide more of the code and more explanation of what you're doing. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. I suspect the issue has something to do with multi-threading but it's hard to say for sure with the partial information available.

Comment: Workarounds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359124/datagridview-throwing-invalidoperationexception-operation-is-not-valid-whe